# why Jupyter Notebook on IPad is too slow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed Jupyter Notebook on my ipad (8th gen) using the following steps:

- I installed ish on ipad from Apple Store, which installed Alpine linux with ash shell.
- Then I installed Python 3.9 on ish
- Then I used pip to install Notebook, after I covered all required dependencies

During the installation of Notebook, some packages took very long time.

After installation completed, running jupyter notebook --allow-root command was successful, there was no delay, and I got a link to the service,...

http://localhost:8888/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I take this link and open it in the ipad chrome, outside ish.

Loading Jupyter main page takes so much time, and it doesn't succeed from the first time.

I try to create new Notebooks, but it opens a blank page and I have to restart the service in order to see the new Notebook on Jupyter main page. Also, it takes so much time to load, and not successful from first trial.

Finally, the same goes for running code even as simple as print statement.

If there is something I can do about this, please inform me. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use colab.research.google.com

Comment: Since iOS lacks virtualization support, the `ish` app runs the Linux environment by emulation, which is much slower.

Comment: During the execution of pip install notebook, some packages took a lot of time to be installed, I believe that these packages are the main cause of slow response of Jupyter.